# Issue using left_join and referring to dataframe columns: Error: Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Apologies in advance for not including a reproducible example, but I'm having some issues with dataframes in RStudio. This only started about 15 minutes ago, and previously working with these dataframes was fine, but now when I try to join two dataframes using `left_join(b09g, b11c, by=c("RAUMID"))`, I get the error `Error: Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment`. The full error using `rlang::last_error()` is pasted below:

```
<error/tibble_error_assign_columns_non_na_only>
Can't use NA as column index in a tibble for assignment.
Backtrace:
    █
 1. ├─gentriclass(b09g) %>% left_join(., b11c, by = c("RAUMID"))
 2. ├─dplyr::left_join(., b11c, by = c("RAUMID"))
 3. └─dplyr:::left_join.data.frame(., b11c, by = c("RAUMID"))
 4.   └─dplyr:::join_mutate(...)
 5.     ├─base::`[<-`(...)
 6.     └─tibble:::`[<-.tbl_df`(...)
 7.       └─tibble:::tbl_subassign(x, i, j, value, i_arg, j_arg, substitute(value))
 8.         └─tibble:::vectbl_as_new_col_index(j, x, value, j_arg, value_arg)
```

Additionally, when I type df$var into the console for just a few select dataframes, a small error message appears next to the text saying `(TypeError) : cannot read property 'substr' of null`.

I'm pretty new to R and Rstudio, and this hasn't ever happened before — I've tried updating both `tidyverse` and updating to the newest version of RStudio, but nothing seems to help.

Edit: I wanted to add that actually calling df$var1 in the console returns the values from this dataframe, and I have no problem viewing the dataframe — it's just referring to columns in joins that creates issues, strangely.

Comment: did you try restarting R and/or RStudio?

Comment: Tried that ;( didn't work. based on reading other posts with similar errors (though not exactly), I'm worried there might be something wrong with the underlying scripts for r/rstudio?

Comment: Then try reinstalling it. should be quick enough. R underneath with all packages should be unaffected by a RStudio reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled RStudio already (downloaded latest version and deleted old version). Made no difference. Interestingly, I'm still able to use `merge(x, y, by="var1)`, even when `x` is giving me the error when I type.

Comment: could you reinstall some of the relevant packages?

Comment: Reinstalled tidyverse, didn’t do anything. Seems like most likely an issue of some sort with dplyr

Comment: could you add a minimu reproducing example of what causes this?

Comment: I've been trying but am unable to reproduce it — I'm really unsure what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is because one of the names of the columns is NA

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33294335)